# How to start a running value using a number not in my data (population estimates)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, cumulative-sum

I am working on a simple matrix for estimating population. Using the number 130,000 as the beginning estimate, which is not in the dataset. I believe I want to use Running Value? I have a calculated field that provides the number of Persons Added by quarter. **How do I use the 130,000 as the base value for the Running Value?** In the screen shot below the first Estimated Pop would be 130,000+317 = 130,317, next row down 130,317+364=130,681.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj4C6.png)

Comment: why can;t you just add `+130000` to the end of your running total expression?

Comment: Adding +130000 to the running total would start me back at a population of 130,000 for each quarter. I want to just start at 130000 and go up not recalculate every quarter from 130000.

Comment: RunningValue(Fields!PersonsAdded.Value,SUM,"PermitBuildingStatistics_Aggregate_rpt_2")+130000)

Comment: Something like this =IIf(Fields!Year.Value=2014 And Fields!Quarter.Value = 1,(RunningValue(Fields!PersonsAdded.Value,SUM,"PermitBuildingStatistics_Aggregate_rpt_2")+130394),
Previous(Fields!EstimatedPop.Value,"PermitBuildingStatistics_Aggregate_rpt_2"))

Comment: when I try the above statement I end it looks like its not taking the value of the row above